# How to make possible vertical scroll on popup and disable vertical scroll for page by using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing responsive web site for small devices. I need to show popup (pure div) and make possible vertical scroll due large content. But instead scrolling my popup main page scrolled.

My question is how could I disable main page scroll and scroll only popup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set height of your `.popup` and then set `overflow` to `auto`

```
.popup{
   height:50px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Now, if your popup has a large contents that doesn't fit in 50 pixels by height and you'll scroll on it, contents in popup will be scrolled instead of whole document contents.

Comment: You could add `html { overflow: hidden; }` so the main page doesn't scroll, unless needed of course

Comment: Is it possible to get it work without setting height in pixels?

Comment: @Erik but what height do you want to have your popups then?

Comment: To fill height of mobile sceen

Comment: @Erik If you want the height of popup to be equal to screen height, set it to 100%.

Comment: Should I set `html { overflow: hidden; }` also?